# Merge file from feature branch into trunk

Tags: svn

Our workflow is as follows:

1. Create feature branch from trunk
2. Do all development in feature branch
3. While working in feature branch, regularly merge trunk into branch to stay in sync with trunk.
4. Once feature is complete, merge back into trunk using `--reintegrate` option.

Suppose I have some work in progress in a feature branch. The entire branch isn't ready to merge back into trunk, but there is one particular file in the branch that I do need to merge to trunk.

What's the easiest way to merge this one file to trunk, without causing any problems later on down the road when it's time to reintegrate the branch back into trunk?

Comment: Any reason you can't checkout the trunk and add the file to the checkout and commit it back?

Comment: @Michael I was thinking about doing this, but wasn't sure it would cause conflicts later on. It seems like the most straightforward approach; I'll give it a try.

Comment: It might cause a conflict for that single file when you merge from the trunk to the development branch. As long as you haven't made any changes you should be safe in just accepting the trunk version.

Answer (score 1):

Try checking out the trunk and adding the file to the checkout and committing it back.

This might cause a conflict for that single file when the first time you merge from the trunk to the development branch. As long as you haven't made any changes you should be safe in just accepting the trunk version.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the file to trunk. But you need to merge the revision created by the merge to trunk back to your branch with the `--record-only` option.

See the "Keeping a Reintegrated Branch Alive" in the [Advanced merging section of the svn book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html)